# How would I implement a widen function on Function1 or PartialFunction

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions, erasure

I would like to define a widen function on Function1 or PartialFunction.

I want to do this because I have a use case similar to the following:

```
class A
class B extends A

def foo(fun: Function[B, A]) = {
    bar(fun.widen[A])
}

def bar(pf: PartialFunction[A, A]) = ???
```

As can be seen above, in order to accomplish this, I thought of defining a widen function such as this:

```
implicit class AugmentedFunction[T, U](fun: T => U) {
    def widen[T1 >: T]: PartialFunction[T1, U] = { case t: T => fun(t) }
}
```

But unfortunately this does not work because of erasure. I tried looking into using TypeTags but I couldn't seem to express this in a way that satisfied the compiler.

**Clarification:**
*When I say it does not work, I mean it throws an exception when used (see ScalaKata code snippet) when it should actually not throw an exception and print "not defined" in the particular case of the code snippet on ScalaKata.*

**My question**:

How could I go about solving this problem correctly? Is there already such functionality in Scalaz or Shapeless that I am unaware of? Does it make any sense to be doing this in the first place?

Here is a snippet with all the code: http://www.scalakata.com/527bb729e4b0b1a1c4db1a73

Comment: It is confusing on what you are trying to do. WHen you do `widen[C]` on function `f: A => B` do you wish that the new returning function should be able to take arguments of type both `A` and `C` ?

Comment: @Jatin You are absolutely correct that I forgot to add a type constraint on T1 to express that a function can only be widened into a  PartialFunction that accepts a super type of the original function parameter type. Thanks for pointing that out, I updated the question with the new type constraint.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this with class manifests:

```
implicit class AugmentedFunction[T, U](fun: T => U)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
  def widen[T1](implicit m1: Manifest[T1]): PartialFunction[T1, U] = {
    case a if(m <:< m1) => fun(a.asInstanceOf[T]) 
  }
}

class A
class B extends A
class C

val theFun: B => A = (b: B) => b

theFun.widen[A].isDefinedAt(new B) // true
theFun.widen[C].isDefinedAt(new C) // false
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem. I have upvoted it but will not accept it just yet because Manifest's are deprecated in Scala 2.10 I believe. I would like to know what would be the solution with TypeTags and contrast the two solutions. I will definitely be using this solution in my code in the meantime though. Thanks again!

Comment: Oops, sorry, I jumped the gun a bit on this one. I added a type constraint a few minutes ago. Widening the function "theFun" to class C does not make any sense and it's totally my fault for forgetting to add the type constraint on the code in the question from the get go. Here is a modified snippet of your code that shows it misbehaving: http://www.scalakata.com/527bbe28e4b0b1a1c4db1a89

Answer (score 0):

Well the error says it all : `java.lang.ClassCastException: ScalaKata$A$1 cannot be cast to ScalaKata$B$1`. Basically when you call `foo( (a: B) => new A, new A)` the `A` value is passed to the lambda which actually accepts type `B` as param and hence the exception while casting from `A` to `B` as that is not possible to cast from generic to specific.

You have to use something like:

```
foo( (a: Ai) => new Ai, new Ai)
foo( (a: Ci) => new Ai, new Ci)
foo( (a: Ai) => new Ai, new Bi)
```

Basically, the 2nd parameter should be a subtype of the lambda argument type.

Comment: My apologies, I should have made the question more clear. The intended purpose of the widen function is to return a PartialFunction that is defined on it's original type but undefined on any other type that is a subtype of the type with which it was widened. So if you pass a super type as I do in the example code in ScalaKata, it should print out undefined instead of throwing an exception. Throwing an exception is a symptom of the widen function misbehaving due to erasure. I will update the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation by using `TypeTag` (because `Manifest` is deprecated)

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

implicit class AugmentedFunction[T : TypeTag, U](fun: T => U) {
  def widen[T1 : TypeTag]: PartialFunction[T1, U] = {
    case a if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[T1] => fun(a.asInstanceOf[T])
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried, but I can't get this to compile, the compiler is complaining about a missing TypeTags for my user types. http://www.scalakata.com/52880709e4b0b1a1c4db55b8

Comment: It is a issue of scalakata. This code is working in REPL and project with compiler 2.10.x (do not forgot include scala-reflect.jar in project dependencies).

Comment: You are right, it does compile in the repl, however it does not give the expected result. Here is the transcript of my repl session: http://pastebin.com/C9r3Z0sU